# Rails ActiveRecord - Order query by matching number

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a model called `Location`. This table has 2 fields I want to order by: `rating` (integer) and `name` (string).

I want to order alphabetically by name, but if the rating is 5, I want that rating to come first. If the rating is anything else except for 5, I want them to unbiasedly show up in alphabetical order after the 5's.

Is this possible to do with SQL? I know I can obviously do this with Ruby's Array#sort, but I want to do this as a query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with a bit of SQL. You'll want to include a `case` expression in your ORDER BY:

```
case rating when 5 then 0 else 1 end
```

That's roughly equivalent to `rating == 5 ? 0 : 1` in Ruby so it will put all the rating 5 locations first and the other locations after. Then sort by `name`:

```
Location.order(Arel.sql('case rating when 5 then 0 else 1 end, name'))
```

Of course, you can hide that in a scope to make things easier to read and understand.

Comment: Awesome thanks. While I have you, is it possible to limit how many 5's are listed first? Meaning if there's 10 instances where rating is 5, only put 3 of them and then just sort the others with the rest?

Comment: It is possible but it starts getting cumbersome with ActiveRecord (or any ORM for that matter) and you have to decide how you want to choose those three that go first.

Comment: For now, I'd just want to choose the first three in alphabetical order by name. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the window function ROW_NUMBER to assign a "sequence" value for each rank. Then apply a the case statement with an added predicate for that "sequence" to satisfy your limit.

```
select rank,name 
  from ( select rank, name 
              , row_number() over (partition by rank
                                       order by rank, name ) rn  
           from location
       ) l
 order by case when rank=5 and rn<=3 then 0 else 1 end   
        , name;
```

Comment: You can avoid the derived table by saying `select * from location order by case when rank = 5 and row_number() over (order by rank, name) <= 3 then 0 else 1 end, name`. DTs are often painful with ORMs.